# How to compare two urls one with www and other without

Tags: c#, url, compare, uri

I am trying to compare 2 urls such as `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` with the expectation the output result would be that they are similar.

I am using the [Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-8.0) to represent the urls and [Uri.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.compare?view=net-8.0) to compare the specified parts of the two Uris using the specified comparison rules.

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
Uri uri2 = new Uri("http://example.com");
var result = 
    Uri.Compare(
        uri1,
        uri2,
        UriComponents.NormalizedHost | UriComponents.PathAndQuery,
        UriFormat.SafeUnescaped, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
    );
Console.WriteLine (result);
```

I have tested with both `UriComponents.Host` and `UriComponents.NormalizedHost` which match the Host data and the Normalized Host respectively, but they both seem to compare the entire domain name of the urls (*[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)* is compared to *example.com*) in this situation. See [UriComponents Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uricomponents?view=net-8.0) for more information.

Is there a way to compare these (urls with *www* and *no www*) using Uri.Compare? If not what other solution would be suitable for such a case?

Comment: If Uri.Compare does not work. It's possible to get the urls in string format and compare them using a regular expression (Regex). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-8.0 There may be a solution with the Uri class, but I'm not too familiar with this class and its features.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: The result of the comparison for the same Url (one prefixed with www and other without) should be the Equal.

Comment: www.example.com and example.com *are different hosts*; one is an "ANAME", the other is a "CNAME" - they are allowed to resolve to different IP addresses and serve completely different content - or they could serve identical content - or one could redirect to the other; unfortunately, "similar" isn't a thing in equality / inequality operations: there is just equal, non equal (for equality) and "less", "more", "equivalent sorting" for inequality; if you want to define your own rules where www.x.com is the same as x.com, great! but: that's not a reliable thing

Comment: _"If Uri.Compare does not work"_ - What do you mean? It _does_ work. It just may not yield the result OP is expecting.

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for the information. This entirely depends on the application. In my case I don't need to resolve Urls to IP addresses. I am validating a Url from User Input and checking to see if the supplied Url matches a Url that already exists.  Users will input with www and others without, some will copy paste the Url etc. This is the my application scenario, thus a custom rule would be suitable as you mentioned.

Comment: (or as a fourth option: they could resolve to the same IP address but still serve different content via host entry mapping)

Comment: @ecemcy it still really depends on what your code does, though; if it is taking input about external sites, and I have two valid different urls, and it *refuses* to accept one: then your code is just *wrong*; if it just *warns me*, then ... maybe I guess; but honestly, I think you should simply treat the url as opaque, and if the user enters the incorrect value: that's a user error; to be explicit: if the host is foo.com and the user says www.foo.com: *the user is mistaken* - just like if they said fuu.com instead of foo.com

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I mean by "doesn't work". If URI class not yield the expecting result, regex can be a solution to compare string urls.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you but your recommendation does not fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

Before providing an answer, I want to acknowledge [@Marc Gravell's point from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778008/how-to-compare-two-urls-one-with-www-and-other-without#comment137117777_77778008):

> `www.example.com` and `example.com` are different hosts; one is an "ANAME", the other is a "CNAME" - they are allowed to resolve to different IP addresses and serve completely different content…

Obviously, *in practice*, we would never *expect* this between `www` and the root domain, per common convention. But Marc's point is relevant because that's why you may not find native support for this in `Uri.Compare()`.

---

#### URL Normalization

Of course, [in absence of sufficient documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uricomponents?view=net-8.0), you'd be forgiven for thinking that `UriComponents.NormalizedHost` *might* do this, so I applaud your effort. After all, [removing (or adding) the `www`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization#Normalizations_that_change_semantics) is within the bounds of [URL normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization):

> **Removing or adding “www” as the first domain label.** Some websites operate identically in two Internet domains: one whose least significant label is “www” and another… [being the] naked domain. For example, `http://www.example.com/` and `http://example.com/` may access the same website. Many websites redirect the user from the www to the non-www address or vice versa. A normalizer may determine if one of these URIs redirects to the other and normalize all URIs appropriately.

I want to highlight that last line, though:

> A normalizer ***may*** determine if one of these URIs redirects to the other and normalize all URIs appropriately

Critically, this should not be *assumed* in URL normalization. Returning to @Marc's point, even a first-order validation of this would require an expensive DNS lookup of the hostnames, and that wouldn't be sufficient in guaranteeing this in the general case, even if it's highly unexpected in this specific case. And, thus returning to [@Marc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778008/how-to-compare-two-urls-one-with-www-and-other-without#comment137117777_77778008):

> …unfortunately, "similar" isn't a thing in equality / inequality operations: there is just equal, non equal (for equality) and "less", "more", "equivalent sorting" for inequality; if you want to define your own rules where `www.x.com` is the same as `x.com`, great! but: that's not a reliable thing

---

#### Some Options

So what to do? Unfortunately, while [@Fadam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77778052/3025856) lacks sufficient detail to answer your question, their point you may need to fall back to string comparison stands.

Unfortunately, this task is made more difficult since the `Uri` class doesn't offer a `Normalize()` *method* to return a normalized URI. That said, the `ToString()` method at least returns the *canonical* version of the URL, and not the *original string* used to construct the `Uri` object. As such, depending on what assumptions you're confident making in your data, you may be able to do something as simple as:

```cs
url1.ToString().Replace("www.", "", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == url2.ToString().Replace("www.", "", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

That said, what I'd recommend is simply to normalize your data going in:

```cs
Uri uri1 = new Uri("http://www.example.com".Replace("www.", "", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Uri uri2 = new Uri("http://example.com".Replace("www.", "", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

(Acknowledging that, in practice, these would be variables from your user input—otherwise we obviously wouldn't require the `Replace()`.)

And then simply continue to use the `String.Compare()` code you already proposed:

```cs
Uri.Compare(
  uri1,
  uri2,
  UriComponents.NormalizedHost | UriComponents.PathAndQuery,
  UriFormat.SafeUnescaped, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
);
```

***Warning:*** If you do this, however, you'll want to to be cautious not to use the trimmed URL outside of this comparison. For instance, a domain may only have an SSL certificate on `www`, so if a user provides `https://www.example.com`, but you persist the value `https://example.com`, that may not function.

I realize this isn't the answer you were *hoping* for, and it's not a very *satisfying* solution, but it's likely the easiest practical and accessible approach.

Of course, depending on the reliability of your data, you could end up going down quite a rabbit hole trying to address all of the possible caveats here—e.g., if, beyond the hostname, you're *also* concerned about other variations, such as trailing slashes, character encoding, query string order, fragments, &c. Using the `Uri.Compare()` approach with `UriComponents.NormalizedHost` will address all of that, but in absence of clear documentation, you'll need to evaluate what all it is normalizing.

Comment: I have tested this and it is quite satisfactory. I am implementing an extension using the information you provided. Taking into account what you and @MarcGravell have recommended, I may need to revisit my use case scenario.